# ArgumentError - invalid value for Integer() for Rails 4.2.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am getting this error while trying to sigin:

```
ArgumentError - invalid value for Integer(): "{:conditions=>{:email=>\"xxx@abc.com\"}":
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:323:in `block in sanitize_limit'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:323:in `sanitize_limit'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:872:in `build_arel'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:858:in `arel'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation.rb:639:in `exec_queries'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation.rb:515:in `load'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation.rb:243:in `to_a'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:500:in `find_nth_with_limit'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:125:in `first'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `first'
  orm_adapter (0.0.7) lib/orm_adapter/adapters/active_record.rb:48:in `find_first'
  devise (1.4.9) lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:118:in `find_for_authentication'
  devise (1.4.9) lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:118:in `find_for_database_authentication'
  devise (1.4.9) lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb:8:in `authenticate!'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/strategies/base.rb:53:in `_run!'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:311:in `block in _run_strategies_for'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:306:in `_run_strategies_for'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:279:in `_perform_authentication'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/proxy.rb:90:in `authenticate'
  devise (1.4.9) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:53:in `current_user'
  devise (1.4.9) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:49:in `user_signed_in?'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:102:in `set_user_time_zone'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
  actionview (4.2.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:49:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:817:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/app_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/meta_request_handler.rb:13:in `call'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.0.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  client_side_validations (4.2.4) lib/client_side_validations/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  rails-dev-tweaks (1.2.0) lib/rails_dev_tweaks/granular_autoload/middleware.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  airbrake (4.3.8) lib/airbrake/rails/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
  better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  rack-contrib (1.4.0) lib/rack/contrib/response_headers.rb:17:in `call'
  meta_request (0.4.0) lib/meta_request/middlewares/headers.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  airbrake (4.3.8) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:16:in `_call'
  airbrake (4.3.8) lib/airbrake/user_informer.rb:12:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.9.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Please help.

Comment: Show your user model  and your schema. I am guessing you have something that checks sign in count but don't have the correct fields in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue. I updated the devise version to 4.2.0. It worked :)

Answer (score 0):

What's inside those lines?

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:102:in `set_user_time_zone'
```

There seems to be some callback (before_action?) set there.
Error invalid value for Integer() is because it tries to apply the sting as Limit, e.g. Limit (10). So somewhere that condition you quoted is passed as Limit - remove it there.